# MySQL Replace value in table by column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `MySQL` table that looks like this, where `pKey` is a primary_AI Key.

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
| pKey | firstName | LastName | Username |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
|    1 | John      | Brown    | jBrown   |
|    2 | Jake      | Smith    | jSmith   |
|    3 | Mary      | Laurier  | mLaurier |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to create a query where it can replace the `LastName` attribute when given a `firstName`. For example, when `firstName` of `John` is supplied, for example, I want to change the last name to `Wilson`.

I wrote this query to replace (or automatically create the row if not exists) the last name when supplied a first name.

```
REPLACE into `myTableName` (LastName, Username) VALUES ("Wilson", "jWilson") WHERE firstName = "John";
```

I'm expecting this query to change the record of `John Brown` to `John Wilson` and the username of `jBrown` to `jWilson`. If the row that has the first name of `John` doesn't exist, I also want it to create a new row with the value of `John` as the `firstName` and `Wilson` as the `LastName` as well as changing the username to `jWilson`.

I know that I can do this with multiple queries, such as `SELECT` the first name, `INSERT` if it does not exist, or `DELETE` the record and `INSERT` it again if it exists, but I have many records I need to insert at once and want to do this in a single query.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a unique constraint defined for the column `firstName`?

Comment: ``firstName`` is unique in this example's case

Comment: It is unique in the sample data you posted, but is it defined as unique in the table?

Comment: It's not defined as unique in the table, but I do know that it will always be unique

Comment: Are you importing data or updating specific rows?

Comment: Then you will have to use 2 separate queries. The 1st will try to update the row (if the name exists) and the 2nd will try to insert the new row (if the name does not exist).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate usernames, you should use:

```
alter table `myTableName` modify column username char(64) unique;
```

To replace (delete then update) into the table

```
REPLACE into `myTableName` (Username) VALUES (CONCAT(SUBSTR(firstname,0,1),lastname))) WHERE firstName = "John";
```

[REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Once it works the way you want it to, remove the WHERE

You can also use [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

```
insert into user (firstname,lastname,username) values ("frank","our",lcase(concat(substr(firstname,1,1),lastname))) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=lcase(concat(substr(firstname,1,1),lastname));
```

If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs.

To update the existing values, use an `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE `myTableName` SET username =  LCASE(CONCAT(SUBSTR(firstname,0,1),lastname))) WHERE firstName = "John";
```

Comment: It appears to work without the ``WHERE``. However, I do not know what the Last Name would be but only the first name. I want to replace the last name when given the first name value of ``John``

Comment: The second example works well on updating the values! Would it be possible to also create those values if they do not exist in the same query (assuming that asides from the nonreplaced values mentioned in the SQL statement can all be null or AutoInc)

Answer (score 1):

A kind of hacky way to do this since you don't want to add the `unique` constraint to the first_name column even though you're sure it's gonna be unique would be to get the pKey of the row where firstName = 'John', and if that doesn't exist, use 0 as pKey instead to let mysql get the next value for you:

```
 INSERT INTO table_name
 select (coalesce((select pKey from table_name where firstName = 'John'),
 0)) as pKey,
 'John' as firstName,
 'Wilson' as lastName,
 'jWilson' as userName
 on duplicate key update lastName = 'Wilson', userName = 'jWilson';
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9091f8d4e8f147b23d01acc1ef31c7ed)